# Can I use JSDom on the frontend to parse html

Tags: reactjs, jsdom

**Has anyone gotten jsdom working in a production react build purely for the frontend (browser)?**

**Background Info**

I got jsdom working for a create-react-app in a dev environment. It's being used to parse an html output that the user creates through a Richtext editor.

**Issue**

The app is not able to be built for **production** due to `whatwg-url` failing since it requires ES6 syntax for Object.defineProperty to work.

Hoping to avoid creating my own regexp's for selecting these html nodes.

Replication:

1. `npx create-react-app my-app; cd my app; npm i jsdom;`
2. Make a file that calls new jsdom and parses a html string
3. Run `npm run build` notice the app fails.

Answer (score 2):

Answering this myself. Short answer, do not use it. There is something called [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) which does something similar to JSDom.